# Am I elligible to contribute to an HSA plan if my spouse is on Medicare?

Tags: insurance, hsa, hdhp

I'm a little confused about the IRS qualification rules for an HSA account specifically with respect to Medicare. The eligibility rules state that You must not be currently enrolled in Medicare.

So, I am employed by a company that provides a HDHP plan that I am signing up for with my spouse as a dependent on the plan. She is on Medicare, but I am not. So does that disqualify me from participating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes you are eligible** even if your spouse is enrolled in Medicare. As long as **YOU** are not enrolled in Medicare you can contribute to an HSA. You may use the money to pay the cost of qualified medical expenses for you and your spouse.

Here are some resources with additional information:

[HSA FAQ's](http://www.napebt.com/forms/hsa_faqs.pdf)

[HSA Resources](http://www.hsaresources.com/faq/)